# Pandas to_csv overwriting, prevent data loss

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a script that is constantly updating a data-frame and saving it to disk (overwriting the old csv-file). I found out that if interrupt the program right at the saving call, `df.to_csv("df.csv")`, all data is losed, and the `df.csv` is empty only containing the column-index.

I can perhaps do a workaround by temporarily saving the data to `df.temp.csv`, and then replacing `df.csv`. But is there a pythonic, short  way to make the saving "Atomary" and prevent data-loss? This is the stack trace I get when interrupting right at the saving call.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/pycharm/2016.1.3/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1531, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/pycharm/2016.1.3/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 938, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Users/user/test.py", line 49, in <module>
    d.to_csv("out.csv", index=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1344, in to_csv
    formatter.save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/formats/format.py", line 1551, in save
    self._save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/formats/format.py", line 1652, in _save
    self._save_chunk(start_i, end_i)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/formats/format.py", line 1666, in _save_chunk
    quoting=self.quoting)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 1443, in to_native_types
    return formatter.get_result_as_array()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/formats/format.py", line 2171, in get_result_as_array
    formatted_values = format_values_with(float_format)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/formats/format.py", line 2157, in format_values_with
    for val in values.ravel()[imask]])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/formats/format.py", line 2108, in base_formatter
    return str(v) if notnull(v) else self.na_rep
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/common.py", line 250, in notnull
    res = isnull(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/common.py", line 73, in isnull
    def isnull(obj):
  File "_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_cython.pyx", line 937, in _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython.ThreadTracer.__call__ (_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_cython.c:15522)
  File "/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/pycharm/2016.1.3/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_is_thread_alive.py", line 14, in is_thread_alive
    def is_thread_alive(t):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: Perhaps you could try appending the results to the old one, like - `d.to_csv("out.csv", index=False, mode='a')`. This prevents them from being overwritten.

Comment: Then the data will be duplicated... Also what happens if I interrupt it right at the saving call? Perhaps no loss, but I think there will be problems also...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a context manager to handle your atomic overwriting:

```
import os
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def atomic_overwrite(filename):
    temp = filename + '~'
    with open(temp, "w") as f:
        yield f
    os.rename(temp, filename) # this will only happen if no exception was raised
```

The `to_csv` method on a Pandas `DataFrame` will accept a file object instead of a path, so you can use:

```
with atomic_overwrite("df.csv") as f:
    df.to_csv(f)
```

The temporary filename I chose is the requested filename with a tilde at the end. You can of course change the code to use something else if you want. I'm also not exactly sure what mode the file should be opened with, you may need `"wb"` instead of just `"w"`.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is to implement a signal handler ([`signal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) module) which waits with terminating the program until the last write operation has finished.

Something along the lines (pseudo-code):

```
import signal
import sys
import time
import pandas as pd

lock = threading.Lock()

def handler(signum, frame):
    # ensure that latest data is written
    sys.exit(1)

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)

while True:
    # might exit any time.
    pd.to_csv(...)
    time.sleep(1)
```